# Identify only number tokens in input (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to calculate the sum of only numeric tokens, and not digits that are attached to words.

#### Example

`"11 M22 33"` — the sum will be 44 because 22 is attached to M

I wrote this function but seems that it's adding all numbers. How do I only isolate the digits-only tokens with regex?

```html
<FORM> 
<input type="text" name="phrase" id="calc" value="Enter code" /> 

<input type="button" value="calcule" onclick="lasomme();" /> 

<input type="button" value="invers" onclick="inverser();" /> 
</FORM> 


<script>

function lasomme() 
{ 

/*var calcule = document.getElementById("calc").value; 
alert(calcule);*/

var k = /^[A-Za-z\-éèàùâêûîôäëüïö]+$/;
var r = /\d+/g;
var s = document.getElementById("calc").value;
var m;
var sam =0;

while ((m = k.r.exec(s)) != null) {
   sam += parseInt(m);
  m++;
  
}
alert (sam);

} 




</script>
```

Is there a way to calculate only numbers and not numbers attached?

Thank you

Comment: will they always be separated by a space in order to be determined as a 'number'? Or can they be separated by commas, dashes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```js
str = "11 M22 33";

sum = str.match(/\b\d+\b/g).reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));

console.log(sum);
```

`\b` is the word-boundary metasymbol, it ensures the expression only matches numbers that are separate words.

Comment: `\b` might or might not be what OP wants - e.g `"Ü11 M22 Ö33"` still adds to `44`

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula:

[`(?:\s|^)\d+(?:\s|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/HVLgLn/1)